# How to extract multi values from xml and parse it to Array

Tags: c++, xml, qt5

I have the following XML entity:
I want to do this mainly because I have an API, and when I query that API, it returns the XML response below. I will extract these values and fill in the UI, but I have trouble when I try to extract values

```
<feed>
    <id></id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated></updated>
    <author>
        <name/>
    </author>
    <link/>
    <entry>
        <id></id>
        <title type="text"></title>
        <updated></updated>
        <category/>
        <link/>
        <link/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                <d:Oper_Id>1</d:Oper_Id>
                <d:Workplace_Id>123456780XYZ</d:Workplace_Id>
                <d:Aenam>WEB_IGL_01</d:Aenam>
                <d:Aedat>2023-11-14T00:00:00</d:Aedat>
                <d:Frequency>1.000</d:Frequency>
                <d:Frequency_Duration>1</d:Frequency_Duration>
                <d:Load_Max>5.000</d:Load_Max>
                <d:Load_Avg>3.000</d:Load_Avg>
                <d:Vertical_Begin>10.000</d:Vertical_Begin>
                <d:Vertical_End>15.000</d:Vertical_End>
                <d:Horizontal_Begin>20.000</d:Horizontal_Begin>
                <d:Horizontal_End>25.000</d:Horizontal_End>
                <d:Asymmetry_Begin>30.000</d:Asymmetry_Begin>
                <d:Asymmetry_End>35.000</d:Asymmetry_End>
                <d:Grip>2</d:Grip>
                <d:Notes>#Test post new workplace from Postman#</d:Notes>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id></id>
        <title type="text"></title>
        <updated></updated>
        <category/>
        <link/>
        <link/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                <d:Oper_Id>2</d:Oper_Id>
                <d:Workplace_Id>123456780XYZ</d:Workplace_Id>
                <d:Aenam>WEB_IGL_01</d:Aenam>
                <d:Aedat>2023-11-14T00:00:00</d:Aedat>
                <d:Frequency>1.000</d:Frequency>
                <d:Frequency_Duration>1</d:Frequency_Duration>
                <d:Load_Max>5.000</d:Load_Max>
                <d:Load_Avg>3.000</d:Load_Avg>
                <d:Vertical_Begin>10.000</d:Vertical_Begin>
                <d:Vertical_End>15.000</d:Vertical_End>
                <d:Horizontal_Begin>20.000</d:Horizontal_Begin>
                <d:Horizontal_End>25.000</d:Horizontal_End>
                <d:Asymmetry_Begin>30.000</d:Asymmetry_Begin>
                <d:Asymmetry_End>35.000</d:Asymmetry_End>
                <d:Grip>2</d:Grip>
                <d:Notes>#Test post new workplace from Postman#</d:Notes>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
       <entry>
        <id></id>
        <title type="text"></title>
        <updated></updated>
        <category/>
        <link/>
        <link/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                <d:Oper_Id>3</d:Oper_Id>
                <d:Workplace_Id>123456780XYZ</d:Workplace_Id>
                <d:Aenam>WEB_IGL_01</d:Aenam>
                <d:Aedat>2023-11-14T00:00:00</d:Aedat>
                <d:Frequency>1.000</d:Frequency>
                <d:Frequency_Duration>1</d:Frequency_Duration>
                <d:Load_Max>5.000</d:Load_Max>
                <d:Load_Avg>3.000</d:Load_Avg>
                <d:Vertical_Begin>10.000</d:Vertical_Begin>
                <d:Vertical_End>15.000</d:Vertical_End>
                <d:Horizontal_Begin>20.000</d:Horizontal_Begin>
                <d:Horizontal_End>25.000</d:Horizontal_End>
                <d:Asymmetry_Begin>30.000</d:Asymmetry_Begin>
                <d:Asymmetry_End>35.000</d:Asymmetry_End>
                <d:Grip>2</d:Grip>
                <d:Notes>#Test post new workplace from Postman#</d:Notes>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
</feed>
```

I would like to take all of these values from 3 entry components:

```
                <d:Oper_Id>2</d:Oper_Id>
                <d:Workplace_Id>123456780XYZ</d:Workplace_Id>
                <d:Aenam>WEB_IGL_01</d:Aenam>
                <d:Aedat>2023-11-14T00:00:00</d:Aedat>
                <d:Frequency>1.000</d:Frequency>
                <d:Frequency_Duration>1</d:Frequency_Duration>
                <d:Load_Max>5.000</d:Load_Max>
                <d:Load_Avg>3.000</d:Load_Avg>
                <d:Vertical_Begin>10.000</d:Vertical_Begin>
                <d:Vertical_End>15.000</d:Vertical_End>
                <d:Horizontal_Begin>20.000</d:Horizontal_Begin>
                <d:Horizontal_End>25.000</d:Horizontal_End>
                <d:Asymmetry_Begin>30.000</d:Asymmetry_Begin>
                <d:Asymmetry_End>35.000</d:Asymmetry_End>
                <d:Grip>2</d:Grip>
                <d:Notes>#Test post new workplace from Postman#</d:Notes>
```

I tried to do the following but it takes separate one by one, and how can I add all to an array?

```
 QDomDocument xmlBOM;
        xmlBOM.setContent(xmlResponse);
        QDomElement root=xmlBOM.documentElement();
        QDomElement Component=root.firstChild().toElement();
        qDebug() << Component.tagName();

        while(!Component.isNull())
        {
            // Check if the child tag name is entry
            QString name = Component.tagName();
            qDebug() << "name " << name;
            // Next component
            Component = Component.nextSibling().toElement();
            qDebug() << "Oper_Id " << QString(Component.elementsByTagName("d:Oper_Id").at(0).firstChild().toText().data());
            qDebug() << "Workplace_Id " << QString(Component.elementsByTagName("d:Workplace_Id").at(0).firstChild().toText().data());
            qDebug() << "Notes " << QString(Component.elementsByTagName("d:Notes").at(0).firstChild().toText().data());
        }
```

Thank you so much

Comment: That's a big data set to work from. Can you replicate the error with something simpler? Perhaps `<feed> <entry> <d:Oper_Id>1</d:Oper_Id> <d:Workplace_Id>123456780XYZ</d:Workplace_Id> </entry> <entry> <d:Oper_Id>2</d:Oper_Id> <d:Workplace_Id>123456780XYZ</d:Workplace_Id> </entry> </feed>`

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell with Xml Linq and output being CSV

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$descendants = $xDoc.Descendants()
$properties = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($descendants,  [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x[0].Name.LocalName -eq 'properties'})

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

foreach($property in $properties)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   foreach($element in $property.Elements())
   {
      $tagname = $element.Name.LocalName
      $value = $element.Value
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $tagname -NotePropertyValue $value
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | Export-CSV -Path $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Results

```
"Oper_Id","Workplace_Id","Aenam","Aedat","Frequency","Frequency_Duration","Load_Max","Load_Avg","Vertical_Begin","Vertical_End","Horizontal_Begin","Horizontal_End","Asymmetry_Begin","Asymmetry_End","Grip","Notes"
"1","123456780XYZ","WEB_IGL_01","2023-11-14T00:00:00","1.000","1","5.000","3.000","10.000","15.000","20.000","25.000","30.000","35.000","2","#Test post new workplace from Postman#"
"2","123456780XYZ","WEB_IGL_01","2023-11-14T00:00:00","1.000","1","5.000","3.000","10.000","15.000","20.000","25.000","30.000","35.000","2","#Test post new workplace from Postman#"
"3","123456780XYZ","WEB_IGL_01","2023-11-14T00:00:00","1.000","1","5.000","3.000","10.000","15.000","20.000","25.000","30.000","35.000","2","#Test post new workplace from Postman#"
```